# script works but PID returns No

Tags: batch-file, pid

I'm trying to create a backup batch file for my W2008 R2 servers that writes its own PID to a file for reference.

The script I use is:

```
@echo off
:loop
::Editeble erea
::Variables   
Title MyBackup
Set caller=MyBackup
Set Drive=C:\Backup
Set Source=Documents
Set SourcePath=C:\Users\Administrator
set BackupCMD=xcopy /v /q /e /k /r /h /y
::End of editeble area
%BackupCMD% "%USERPROFILE%\%Source%" "%drive%"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
set "oldpids="
for /f "TOKENS=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %caller%" /NH') do set "oldpids=!oldpids!%%b"
echo %oldpids% >> test2.txt
timeout /t 3595 /nobreak
goto loop
```

I build his script with already loads of anwsers from this site and it works till the point where it has to tell me the PID.

Comment: did you forget `setlocal enabledelayedexpanison`?

Comment: 1. remove `@echo off` and check out what is happening; 2. execute your `tasklist` command line outside of `for` to see whether it returns the line you expect (maybe `caller` does not contain the correct filter value?); 3. why do you concatenate `oldpids`? why not simply using `set oldpids=%%b` in your `for` loop?

Comment: @aschipfl if more than one instance is running, he gets more than one PID. (although a delimiter between them would be helpful: `set "oldpids=!oldpids!-%%b"`)

Comment: Hmm... the OP is talking about "the PID", and I guessed he wants to know the PID of the running batch script...

Comment: @KaiBödder, the actual window title is probably `Administrator: MyBackup`

Comment: I've tried it all but when i turn echo off and look and the work sequence it tells me that there is no active task running.

In Taskmanager it tells me that CMD.exe is running, but its not returning anything.

Comment: Okay never mind... Figured it out there where 2 spaces between Administrator: and MyBackup